# Disable carousel in Bootstrap 3 auto resize on Mobile devices (Height)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm working on a website but I'm struggling to get my Bootstrap carousel to work properly. On normal screens it works great, but whenever I look at the website on a mobile device (or shrink the page on my desktop) the carousel is adjusting itself to be responsive. However, this causes my carousel to shrink to sizes where the carousel is displayed, but only has around 5 pixels in height making it look really strange.

You can find my test website [here](http://goo.gl/66y7bw) to see it yourself, is there any way how I can fix this issue by either:

- Removing the carousel completely whenever the height is below 100px;
- Adjusting the carousel to only shrink horizontally or at least not shrink this much;

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mediaqueries can be helpfull in this certain case. You can tel it  simply have a `display: none;` when you go under 100 pixels, if that is what you want. I must point that your second option is not gonna work, cause you ll change the format (the picture is getting stretched in ackward ways - verhoudingsgewijs als je me snapt). I would go for option 1.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and go for the @media, thanks!

Comment: Just noticed you live in Groningen as well ^.^ Anyway, I tried your solution and I tested around a little, I think this is indeed the best way to go. I had to add a second @media query to add some margin-top to the div below the carousel, but now it works greatly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try post your codes next time, would make it alot easier to solve your problems.

First of all you should margin top your carosuel so your navbar doesnt overlab your carosuel.

I cannont help you with your collapse problem since i cannot see your code.

add this to your stylesheet:

```
.carousel {
   margin-top: 91px;
}
```

Comment: My problem was already fixed, thanks though. I posted a link to the page where you could see the problem and see the code as well, as it is just html/css/js.

Comment: people dont wanna go and visit your site to view the code

Comment: Well, you* don't, you cannot speak for people in general as some other people here did visit the website to check out the problem.. It wasn't even a code program, more of a logical problem. Posting the code here wouldn't have been any help ;p

Answer (score 0):

Try class img-responsive in image tag, maybe it fix your problem.

Comment: That didn't work, as img-responsive simulates the effect of the carousel itself (in fact, the Bootstrap carousel by default has the same properties as img-responsive).